# Events Manager: Create custom Placeholder for use in Email notification

Tags: plugin-development, events

I have written a function (child-theme; functions.php) for the plugin Event-Manager in Wordpress.
This function reads values out of custom input fields and saves those in the databse.

I would like to write a custom Placeholder in order to place it in the email notification.

The function is:

```
function em_save_custom_event_fields() {
    global $EM_Booking;
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['user_motorcycle'])) {
        $EM_Booking->booking_meta['registration']['user_motorcycle'] = wp_kses($_Request['user_motorcycle'], array());
    }
}
add_filter('em_booking_add, em_save_custom_event_fields');
```

For the email notification I would like to add a new placeholder called #_USERMOTORCYCLE in the template that actually replaces the placeholder with the value that was provided by the user and stored at:

```
$EM_Booking->booking_meta['registration']['user_motorcycle']
```

I have searched the web and found some samples but as a novice I am not able to apply them to my requirements.

[Create a Custom Placeholder for Event Formatting](https://wp-events-plugin.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-placeholder-for-event-formatting/)
and
[Show specific database value in notification email](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-specific-database-value-in-notification-email/)

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with the same issue at the moment. It seems that placeholders are scattered everywhere through the plugin files making it a little difficult to reproduce.

Edit: Alright, it seems that there might be an easier way though I'm sure you might need to keep looking for something better. Go to the events-manager/classes folder, and open em-booking.php. In the output function you can add your own placeholder. Something along the lines of:

```
     case '#_USERMOTORCYCLE':
                $replace = $this->get_person()->user_motorcycle;
                break;
```

That should do the trick for now.

Comment: That didn‘t work for me so far. The e-mail Placeholder stays the same („User_Motorcycle: #_USERMOTORCYCLE“). I‘ve added the following: case '#_BOOKINGSUMMARY':
     ob_start();
     em_locate_template('emails/bookingsummary.php', true, array('EM_Booking'=>$this));
     $replace = ob_get_clean();
     break;
                                 case '#_USERMOTORCYCLE':
                                         $replace = $this->booking_meta['registration']['user_motorcycle'];
                                          break;
    default:
     $replace = $full_result;
     break;